# The proper way of asking this “would you mind...” question

Tags: word-choice, gerunds, politeness

I know this is not properly written:

> “Would you please mind a minute to answer my messages?”

Is this the correct way?

> “Would you mind taking a minute to answer my messages please?”

Or where should the “please” word go?

Comment: **“Would you mind taking a minute to answer my messages please?”** is correct. *Would you mind* is already being used as a "polite" word so I think "please" can be omitted.

Comment: @BellaSwan -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

The correct one is

> “Would you mind taking a minute to answer my messages please?”

To correct the first one, it could rather be written as,

> “Would you please mind **taking** a minute to answer my messages?”

(The position of please is not the thing causing the problem here)

Also, *Would you mind* is already being used as a "polite" phrase, so "please" can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

> Would you mind taking a minute to answer my messages please?

If you want to say, "please," and that's a good thing, it's not wrong grammatically to add it. Whether you should say "please" or not when making a request falls into the realm of manners, not grammar. Whether you should say "please" in addition to asking in a polite manner is a judgement call on your part. It is not purely a grammatical consideration. You can place "please" where you did in your corrected sentence.

See this link for an extended discussion of where to place "please."

["Could you please help me" vs "Could you help me please"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18153/could-you-please-help-me-vs-could-you-help-me-please/18154#18154)